# Why do I get "ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer" while converting from .hdf5 to .tflite in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I used a pretrained model from Tensorflow hub to train on my data and it gave me significantly higher val_acc. I saved the model as a .hdf5 file and intend to convert it into .tflite so I can import to my android application. This is the code I used in converting:

```
from tensorflow_core.lite.python.lite import TFLiteConverter
model_path = 'C:/Users/1/Desktop/data_sets/86%.hdf5'
converter = TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(model_path)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

it outputs "ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer"

I am using tf version 2.0.
This is how I saved the model. The below code was in a callback.

```
ModelCheckpoint(filepath=data_dir + '/weights.hdf5', monitor='val_accuracy',
verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
```

[photot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix2HJ.png)